# Doxygen: how to link to an user-defined anchor of a Doxygen-generated HTML file?

Tags: doxygen

I am using Doxygen 1.8.17 and CMake 3.14+ to document an old legacy Fortran 77 application.

I can't solve the following use case with Doxygen:

> One subroutine, located in a file named `myenum.f90`, defines some values for Doxygen documentation and an @anchor command is set.

```
!> @brief get myenum
subroutine get(myenum)
!> @param[out] myenum
   integer myenum

   !> @anchor enum_myenum myenum's meaning
   !! value  | meaning
   !! :-----:|:-------:
   !! 1      |left
   !! 2      |center
   !! 3      |right 

   !> Compute myenum (code skipped)
   myenum = 1   
end subroutine
```

> The other subroutine, located in a file named `dosomething.f90`, uses these values and references the anchor to avoid documentation duplication.

```
!> do something based on myenum
subroutine dosomething(myenum, mystuff)
    integer myenum !< @param[in] myenum [based on myenum enumerate](@ref enum_myenum)
    character*(*) mystuff !< @param[out] my stuff

    if (myenum.eq.1) then
        mystuff='left'
    elseif (myenum.eq.2) then
        mystuff='center'
    elseif (myenum.eq.3) then
        mystuff='right'
    endif
end subroutine
```

A hyperlink is created inside the file `dosomething<...>.html` generated by Doxygen. The link's target is not the file `myenum<...>.html` generated by Doxygen but instead the Fortran file `myenum.f90`.

Is there a way to set the link's target to `myenum<...>.html` at the anchor's location ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen has a number of ways to create links, with the `@ref` command, using markdown syntax, some automatic linking etc. It is also possible to use the `\link ...\endlink` construct.

From your example (and my tests) it looks like that the the `@ref` and markdown syntax don't work in this case.
I tried the to use the `\link..` command as well and this(as far as I can see) works, my, a little bit extended, example:

```
!> do something based on myenum                                                                                                     subroutine dosomething(myenum, mystuff, mythird)
    integer myenum           !< @param[in]  [based on markdown syntax with @@ref](@ref enum_myenum)
    character*(*) mystuff    !< @param[out] @ref enum_myenum Based on @@ref command
    double precision mythird !< @param[out] @link enum_myenum based on @@link command \endlink

    if (myenum.eq.1) then
        mystuff='left'
    elseif (myenum.eq.2) then
        mystuff='center'
    elseif (myenum.eq.3) then
        mystuff='right'
    endif
end subroutine
```

Also with the current doxygen version 1.8.18 and the current master (1.8.19 (cd581388f3d013c501e3cefbaf3e81cf93d46fcb)) the problem is still present.

It is definitely worth submitting an issue / bug report in the doxygen issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: Thanks a lot, @albert. The \link ... \endlink command works in my case. I will submit an issue this afternoon and I will update this post with the issue ID.

Comment: I submit the following issue in the doxygen tracker https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7715